# Cannot use Cairo in Monodevelop on Debian linux

Tags: linux, mono, monodevelop, cairo

I want to create my own GTK# widget, and so I need to use Cairo for custom painting. But there is a big problem - Cairo library is not recognized on my machine.

At statement **`using Cairo;`** Monodevelop says: **`The name 'Cairo' does not exist in the current context`**, and so I cannot even compile my sources. I have tried to disable source analysis, but obviously this is deeper problem.

I use Debian testing and all libmono-cairo* libraries are installed.
Is there any way how to got Cairo working on Debian linux?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `libmono-cairo*` are installed, you surely missed adding `Mono.Cairo` to your references:

[image]

Check `Mono.Cairo` to add cairo wrapper assembly to your project.

If you can't find `Mono.Cairo` in the Packages, go to `.net Assembly` Tab, and browse
    /usr/lib/mono/4.0/
Or any other cli version, and add `Mono.Cairo.dll` to your references.

*note:*

I've double check why on `Debian` (`jessie` for me) `Mono.Cairo` doesn't appear in the reference list even if `Mono-cairo.pc` is present in `pkgconfig` directory. Launching Monodevelop as Root, it appears in the Packages list. So must there be a permission failure somewhere.

Comment: Why didn't I think of this before? You have to do this in Visual Studio too.